# Need help to form a regex in java

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver

I want to find a regx and occurrences of it in the page source using language Java. The value I am trying to search is as given in the program below.
There might be one or more spaces between tags. I am not able to form a regx for this value. Can some one please help me to find the regx for this value?
My program which checks regx is as given below-

---

```
String regx=""<img height=""1"" width=""1"" style=""border-style:none;"" alt="""" src=""//api.adsymptotic.com/api/s/trackconversion?_pid=12170&_psign=3841da8d95cc1dbcf27a696f27ccab0b&_aid=1376&_lbl=RT_LampsPlus_Retargeting_Pixel""/>";

WebDrive driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("abc.xom");
int count=0, found=0;
source = driver.getPageSource();
source = source.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
pattern = Pattern.compile(regx);
matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

while(matcher.find())
{   
    count++;
    found=1;
}   
if(found==0)
{   
    System.out.println("Maximiser not found");
    pixelData[rowNumber][2] = String.valueOf(count) ;
    pixelData[rowNumber][3] = "Fail";
}   
else
{   
    System.out.println("Maximiser is found" + count);
    pixelData[rowNumber][2] = String.valueOf(count) ;
    pixelData[rowNumber][3] = "Pass";

}   
count=0; found=0;
```

Comment: XPath should be more appropriate than regex in your case :) On the top of my head, something like `count(\\img[@height="1" and @width="1" and ...])`

Comment: Your code doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without the original text and expected result, but your `Pattern` clearly won't compile as is.

You should single-escape double quotes (`\"`) and double-escape special characters (i.e. `\\?`) for your code **and** your `Pattern` to compile.

Something in the lines of:

```
String regx="<img height=\"1\" width=\"1\" style=\"border-style:none;\" " +
            "alt=\"\" src=\"//api.adsymptotic.com/api/s/trackconversion" +
            "\\?_pid=12170&_psign=3841da8d95cc1dbcf27a696f27ccab0b" +
            "&_aid=1376&_lbl=RT_LampsPlus_Retargeting_Pixel\"/>";
```

Also consider scraping markup with appropriate framework (i.e. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for HTML) instead of regex.

Comment: Thanks Mena. I tried it but it didn't work :(. I will check JSoup. But I am checking other value - <script src="/scripts/marketing/mmcore.js"></script>
which works fine.

Comment: @ForTesting you're welcome. With such a long query and no info on the whole text, it's hard to help you. Also consider you're looking for a literal in this case, to you might not need a `Pattern` after all! You could remove the double-escapes and try again with `String.contains` or `String.indexOf`...

Comment: Thanks Mena. I tried to split this regx string and used String.contains. It worked fine.